# Android borders on individual views

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, border, android-framelayout

I have trouble making borders for android views

What I try to do for simulating a border is to create a view with the main background, then create a view around it with the border color as the background. the first view then has a padding around it, but the wrapping border view still does not show reliably

How do I fix this problem and what is a better way to add a border color around an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [Shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) (make it a rectangle, define a stroke) and use that shape as the background of yout view. You can also define rounded corners.

If you need something more elaborated, you can make a 9-patch image and use that as the background.